# How a bool type variable is stored in memory? (C++)

Tags: c++, boolean

bool test;

`sizeof(test) = 1` if using VS 2010. Since every C++ data type must be addressable,
the "test" bool variable is 8-bits(1 byte).

My question is that does the "test" variable really occupy 1 byte in memory?

Is there any implementation skill that can make the bool data type occupy only
one bit? If yes, can you give me an example?

`bool test1[32]`(in VS 2010), 
`int test2`(in VS 2010)

Do `test1` and `test2` occupy the same memory?

Comment: Let me emphasize that it could be reasonable for a platform to store a boolean in 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine when hyper-optimising for speed. Then if you'd have 4 booleans in a structure, you'd only need a single ALU operation for checking if a bool is true, compared to two when there are many booleans packed in one machine word. (Ofc such a small difference is normally not important at all.)

Comment: Some embedded processors actually have bit addressable memory, so that the bool variable can occupy one bit.

Answer (score 10):

Every element of `test1` must be addressable. This implies that array `test1` (that was created using `bool test1[32]`) takes at least 32 bytes (1 byte per element).

If you want multiple boolean values to be stored in a single variable, use `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>` (but be aware that the latter is not really a vector of bools, it is a specialization designed to save space).

IIRC, C++11 also defines `std::dynamic_bitset`.

Comment: you probably mean 32 bits, not bytes

Comment: If the processor has 8-bit addressable units, that would imply that a `bool` must occupy 1 octect (byte), not 4 (32-bits).  And yes, there are still 8-bit addressable systems out there.  The ARM9 can access 8 or 32 bit values.

Comment: @entity64: `test1` is an array of 32 addressable `bool` objects, which will need (at least) 32 bytes, one per object.

Comment: Doh! - didn't see that. Sorry :-)

Comment: @entity64: no, I mean 32 **bytes**, where a byte is one unit of least storage (not necessarily 8 bits), as mandated by the C++ standard.

Comment: 2 years later... Yeah, dynamic_bitset, sure. Thanks for that, <guys who do standards>!

Answer (score 3):

> My question is that does the "test" variable really occupy 1 byte in memory?

Yes, if `sizeof(bool)==1` . Basically, the sizeof bool is implementation-defined, which means it could be greater than 1 byte for certain compiler.

> bool test1[32](in VS 2010), int test2(in VS 2010)
>   Does test1 and test2 occupy the same memory?

What each of them occupy can be known by using sizeof operator. That is what sizeof operator is for. So `test1` and `test2` will occupy `sizeof(test1)` and `sizeof(test2)`  **bytes** respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility to have a variable of 1 bit, is to put into a bitfield struct:

```
struct {
    int a:1;
    int b:1;
};
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `unsigned a : 1`?

Comment: Well, I'm sure I used it this way, though I have never considered it as a 1-bit signed integer, so you have a point here.