# How is a bool represented in memory?

Tags: c++, types, boolean

As already discussed [in the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/), a `bool` data type occupies at least a byte of memory. A similar question was asked on SO before ([How a bool type variable is stored in memory? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967924/how-a-bool-type-variable-is-stored-in-memory-c)), but this discussion and the documentation only seem to discuss the amount of space occupied by a boolean data type, not what actually happens *in memory* when I do this:

`bool b = true;`

So what does actually happen in memory? What happens to the 7 bits that are not used in storing this information? Does the standard prescribe behavior for this?

Are they undefined? Or did someone at C++ headquarters just do this:

```
enum bool : char 
{
  false = 0,
  true = 1
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How a bool type variable is stored in memory? (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967924/how-a-bool-type-variable-is-stored-in-memory-c)

Comment: [OT]The notion of "C++ headquarters" made me laugh; it strikes me as a gray place with dusty copies of the standard all around and hundreds of language lawyers questioning over STL vs stdlib and similar diatribes.[/OT]

Comment: As an extension to this question, would I be better off using char (single byte) as a opposed to a bool?

Comment: Related: [Does the C++ standard allow for an uninitialized bool to crash a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120862) - some ABIs do define the object-representation for `bool` that way, so compilers are allowed to assume that it won't ever read some other other bit-pattern (like `42`) from a `bool`.  Thus if it does, it's UB.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Standard states that `bool` values behave as integral types, yet it doesn't specify their concrete representation in memory:

*"Values of type `bool` are either `true` or `false`. As described below, `bool` values behave as integral types. Values of type `bool` participate in integral promotions"* <sub>~ C++03 3.9.1 §6</sub>

*"A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system"* <sub>~ C++03 3.9.1 §7</sub>

Yet it defines the integral promotion from `bool` to `int`:

***"An rvalue of type `bool` can be converted to an rvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one. These conversions are called integral promotions."*** <sub>~ C++03 4.5 §4-5</sub>

as well as conversion from other types to `bool`:

***"A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`."*** <sub>~ C++03 4.12 §1</sub>

Comment: C++14 specifies that `bool` *is* an integral type and uses a pure binary numeration system, although it still doesn't say exactly what that means. We might expect `false` to have the same representation as `0`, and `true` to have the representation of `1` but it does not actually say that.

Answer (score 6):

The standard doesn't mandate anything for the binary representation of bools; it just says that, when converting to other integral types, a `true` bool will become 1 and a `false` bool will become 0.

This of course suggests an implementation similar in spirit to the one you said, where such conversions would become essentially no-ops or plain integer widening (but remember that `bool` is mandated to be a primitive type, not an enumeration type).

Answer (score 5):

You can test things like this by copying the memory, ignoring which type it is. This program reads the raw memory value of `test_bool` and puts it into `test_int` so that you may print it.

```
int test_int = 0;
bool test_bool;

test_bool = true;
memcpy (&test_int, &test_bool, sizeof(bool));
printf ("True value is: %d\n", test_int);

test_bool = false;
memcpy (&test_int, &test_bool, sizeof(bool));
printf ("False value is: %d\n", test_int);
```

For me, this program gives:

```
True value is: 1
False value is: 0
```

Comment: It would be more meaningful to copy the `bool` to a `char` (or better, to a `char[sizeof(bool)]`), otherwise the interpretation of this half-overwritten `int` may be complicated by other issues (on a 32-bit big-endian machine with `true` stored as a single-byte 1, for example, your code would output 16777216).

Comment: Yes, probably best to use a type of the same size as bool.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't program in C++ since a couple of months but AFAIR the rule is the following:
0 - false;
any value different than 0 - true; (by default it's 1 but AFAIR if you convert it from other integer value, ex. 2 will be also treated as true).

Thus you can say that C++ in some way waste memory (others too) as it could use one bit only but it's simpler to make compiler then.

In C++ you can also define bit fields [(bit fields in wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) but it's not used often.

Comment: Careful - what the `bool` type stores and what is the notion of `true` for a conditional instruction is different stuff...