# Can a C++ compiler represent bool internally with something other than 0 or 1?

Tags: c++

The following questions (and answers) indicate that a bool's value when converted to int will be 0 or 1.

1. [Is C/C++ bool type always guaranteed to be 0 or 1 when typecast'ed to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276207/is-c-c-bool-type-always-guaranteed-to-be-0-or-1-when-typecasted-to-int)
2. [c++ bool question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189072/c-bool-question)

My question is whether *the compiler can represent the value as something else internally* (up to the conversion).  I vaguely recalling the MSVC debugger show the numeric value of the byte representing the bool if it isn't 0 or 1, and I seem to recall seeing 255 sometimes (0xFF).

Said differently, *could the following code return something other than 0 or 1?*

```
int boolval(bool z) {
  return *(unsigned char *)&z;
}
```

I am currently working with a binary format that uses `bool`'s in the structure and am seeing 255's instead of 0's and 1's.

EDIT: I just found an almost identical questions a moment ago so I am linking it here for more information.
[How is a bool represented in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351483/how-is-a-bool-represented-in-memory)
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `bool` in-memory representation is implementation-defined, I'll try to find a standard quote for this.

Comment: Are the `bool`s bitfields by any chance?

Comment: Aren't you answering your own question there?

Comment: @filmor, "implementation-defined" means the implementation must document its choice, maybe you mean unspecified (which doesn't have to be documented)

Comment: yes it can, but in practice you won't find a compiler that uses anything but 0 and 1. other values can occur due to UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler can represent true however it likes as long as `1==(int)true` and `0==(int)false`

The simplest way for the compiler to meet those requirements is to represent `false` as all zero bits and `true` as the least significant bit set, because then the "conversion" to `int` doesn't involve changing anything.

But the compiler is free to represent `true` as all bits set, and issue instructions to convert that to `1` when converted to `int`, or even to represent `true` as all zero bits and `false` as all bits set or any other odd representation, as long it meets the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

[basic.fundamental]/6:

> Types `bool`, […] are collectively called integral types. A synonym
>   for integral type is integer type. 
> **The representations of integral
>   types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system.**

This is vague. In no way does the standard require `false` and `true` to correspond to `0` or `1` in memory (it could be the other way around). What we do know is that the representation obviously doesn't change, so you will get consistent results.

However, the following rules apply to the [x86_64 processor specific ABI](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.95.pdf):

> Booleans, when stored in a memory object, are stored as single byte
>   objects the value of which is always 0 (false) or 1 (true). **When
>   stored in integer registers or passed as arguments on the stack, all 8
>   bytes of the register are significant; any nonzero value is considered
>   true.**

The value will for that ABI then be `0` for `false` and anything for `true`. It's not guaranteed which value will be returned from your function in that case.

Comment: That's true for the x86 psABI (see p13 of http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.95.pdf although it says all bits are significant for parameters, with any non-zero value being true), I don't know if e.g. the MS compiler uses that ABI though.

Comment: Well, these rules have nothing to do with x86: You can write implementations on x86 that do not follow these rules, and you can write implementations on all other systems that follow these rules... It's all down to what ABI you are using.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ahh, there it is. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant to say  that's the **x86_64** psABI. The Intel386 psABI doesn't seem to mention `bool` at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts of this question:

1) What do compilers actually do?

- All major compiler currently represents false as 0
- Some compilers however do not represent true always as 1,
  but rather whatever value the source had, so that in 
  `bool ok = res;` ok will have whatever value res had.

2) What do the standard say?

- No guarantees!

Comment: Ehm, in what way can you count on false being represented as 0?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you cant, I reformulated that part